# Get cross domain client-side request page contents

Tags: javascript, php, client-server, cross-domain, httprequest

I have a bit of a problem. I need to get the contents of a page, but it must be requested from the client machine (with client ip - essentially). And I need to access the content string on either server or client side. The page is from a different domain than the page the user's initially on. Whichever language or technology to be used, doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing, please elaborate! What means client machine? What have you tried? Can you give us an example?

Comment: I'm building a web app accessing a cross domain third party webpage that takes visitor's ip and uses it to make some sort of a key. Now, i need to recreate that key for my client's ip address. It's either to request the page from server side script with ip spoofing, or to request it from client side script and override cross-domain policy.

Answer (score 1):

I am dealing with a similar problem.
[Meteor js use http.get to retrieve json data from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353835/meteor-js-use-http-get-to-retrieve-json-data-from-a-webpage)

If your working with meteor js check this out.
http://meteorserver.org
its the section titled "Cross site scripting support"

This link I have also found helpful.
http://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/